# b a ba, /beaba/ or /bøaba/?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

A teacher I had made a point of pronouncing *le b a ba* /ləbøaba/ and sounded the letter *b* the way it is sounded when reading is taught to young children, /bø/ and not /be/, as you would sound /ʀø/ instead of /ɛʀ/ for the letter *r*.  I never saw any record of this pronunciation in any dictionary, and yet /bøaba/ makes perfect sense to me.

Another issue is spelling.  It is spelt in different ways, but always with dots and hyphens, whereas you find it spelt in Saint-Simon's *Memoirs* as *b a, ba*, which once again I find more simple and logical.

Comment: La lettre B se prononce /be/ et je n'ai jamais entendu d'enseignant la prononcer  /bø/. J'ai donc beaucoup de mal à comprendre (mais je ne mets pas en doute ce que tu dis bien sûr...). Pour l'orthographe rien a rajouter à ce que dit le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b.a.%20ba). Pour information le *dictionnaire culturel en langue française* écrit B.A.-BA.

Comment: @Laure Dans l'article "b" du TLF, dans la partie prononciation et orthographe, on trouve cette indication :  LAND. 1834 : ,,On prononce Bé (...) L'E est fermé. Les Maîtres d'École font prononcer Be, e muet.  Ce "Land." renvoie à Napoléon Landais et à son Dictionnaire général et grammatical des dictionnaires français.  C'est cette prononciation de "maître d'école" que je décris dans ma question.  Mais peut-être n'a-t-elle plus cours de nos jours.

Comment: Je confirme que ceci n'a plus cours de nos jours. (et remarque personnelle : heureusement !).

Comment: @None Ouais, pourquoi faire simple alors qu'on peut faire compliqué...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cette prononciation simplifiée n'est plus utilisée mais l'était encore dans certaines écoles primaires au moins jusqu'aux années 1930.

L'alphabet était alors déclamé comme suit :

> **A** **BEU QUEU DE** **E** **FEU GUEU HEU** **I** **JEU QUEU LEU MEU NEU** **O** **PEU QUEU REU SEU TEU** **U** **VEU** <s>WEU</s><sup>1</sup> **XEU** **Y**<sup>2</sup> **ZEU**

Cette manière de prononcer facilitait l'apprentissage des syllabes et a donné la forme **/bø a ba/**.

Un inconvénient était l'indifférenciation de *C*, *K* et *Q*.

Cette technique qui a donc subsisté jusqu'au début du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle a été introduite en 1660 dans la [Grammaire de Port-Royal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaire_de_Port-Royal) :

> CHAPITRE VI
>
> D'une nouvelle manière pour apprendre à lire facilement en toutes sortes de langues.
>
> Cette méthode regarde principalement ceux qui ne savent pas encore lire.
> Il est certain que ce n'est pas une grande peine à ceux qui commencent, que de connoître simplement les lettres ; mais que la plus grande est de
> les assembler.
> Or, ce qui rend maintenant cela plus difficile, est que chaque lettre ayant son nom, on la prononce seule autrement qu'en l'assemblant avec
> d'autres.
> [...]
> Il semble donc que la voie la plus naturelle,
> comme quelques gens d'esprit l'ont déjà remarqué,
> seroit que ceux qui montrent à lire, n'apprissent
> d'abord aux enfans à connoître leurs lettres, que
> par le nom de leur prononciation ; [...]
> Qu'on ne leur nommât aussi les consonnes que
> par leur son naturel, en y ajoutant seulement l'e
> muet, qui est nécessaire pour les prononcer : par
> exemple, qu'on donnât pour nom à b, ce qu'on
> prononce dans la dernière syllabe de tombe; à
> d celui de la dernière syllabe de ronde; et ainsi des
> autres qui n'ont qu'un seul son.
> Que pour celles qui en ont plusieurs, comme c,
> g, t, s, on les appelât par le son le plus naturel
> et plus ordinaire, qui est au c le son de que, et au
> g le son de gue, au t le son de la dernière syllabe
> de forte, et à l's celui de la dernière syllabe de
> bourse.

On retrouve quelques vestiges de cette prononciation dans SNCF parfois encore prononcé « pour rire », /sø nø sø fø/ (**seu neu ce feu**) et l'équipe de football de Toulouse (TFC: [Toulouse Football Club](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toulouse_Football_Club_(1937))) originalement appelée /tø fø sø/ (**teu feu seu**), et qui a gardé jusqu'à aujourd'hui (même si c'est un autre club qui a repris le même nom) une prononciation particulière du *F* : /te fe se/ (**[téfécé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toulouse_Football_Club)**).

La prononciation moderne est **/be a ba/** et elle s'est lexicalisée en un mot ***[B.A. BA](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b.a.%20ba)*** ou mieux ***[b.a.-ba](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b.a.-ba)*** qui signifie rudiments les plus basiques d'un savoir, d'une connaissance. Grevisse écrit ***béaba***.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Le W n'était pas enseigné comme une lettre distincte à cette époque.</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>Prononcé comme I.</sub>

Comment: Pour autant que je m'en souvienne, **C** était prononcé **SEU** et non **QUEU** dans les années soixante.

Comment: @toto C'est possible, ou même **CÉ** comme aujourd'hui. Les instituteurs avaient alors plus de liberté.

Comment: Intéressant, je serais curieux de connaitre une source qui parle de cet alphabet déclamé A BEU QUEU etc. !

Comment: @XouDo Référence ajoutée pour l'origine de cette technique d'apprentissage.

Answer (score 1):

The letter b is pronounced "bé", but when we are explaining how to pronounce a word, we say "beuh", for example, the word "bain", A - I - N is pronounced « in », beuh + in = bain